# How can the content of the HTML in RSS be extracted info fields even if they are not in the RSS it self?

Tags: feeds

As RSS files do not contain the actual content of the pages, how can a feed processor load the HTML in the linked page and extract some content from it into the target content type?

Coming to think of it isn't actually an RSS issue, it is about taking a list of URLs, loading the actual pages and extracting data elements from them into the fields of a content type.

Do some of the node processors have that capability?

Comment: I've tried something like this in the past too, but I have forgotten the exact steps to achieve this. I think you will need the Feeds Spider module for this, but it also possible that I had used the Feeds Crawler module, which is quite similar to Feeds Spider.

Comment: Feed Crawler and Feeds Spider are the modules I am looking to, but the docs for them are sketchy

Comment: I agree. I too found them hard to use.